# how do I queue installations?

Tags: software-installation

I'm running an installation through terminal, I open another session and try to run another installation while the 1st one is still running, and (of course) I get a "locked resource" message. Is there any way I can queue the 2nd installation? This is only when I forget to "apt install X Y Z", I know I can install multiple packages with one command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aptdaemon, a fairly obscure low-level service, provides the capability to queue apt package actions from d-bus.

The Ubuntu Software application uses this capability. You can click on 'install' or 'remove' while a package action is already in progress, and the selection will be queued for later execution.

No other apt frontends have yet written queuing features, so ordinary users have no convenient way (yet) to use the feature outside of Ubuntu Software.

It cannot be triggered directly by shell commands. It can be triggered indirectly using dbus shell commands. The nomenclature of such a command is tricky, and not easy for common usage. But it does exist.

See `man aptd` for more information.